Existence and uniqueness of solution of system of differential equations
We have the system of differential equation $\dot{x}=f(x, t)$, where $f:G\times [0, \infty)\to \mathbb{R}^n$, where $G\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.
Here, $f$ is a Lipchitz continuous on any closed and bounded time interval $[a, b]$. Can we prove the existence and uniqueness using Picard's Lindloff theorem? Because, the initial condition need not to be in the interior of the given domain only.
I have referred some research articles, they have discussed positive invariance of solution before discussing the existence of the solution. Is it possible to discuss in that way?
